# Gradle compile dependencies with/out "@aar" what is the difference?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have gradle dependencies configuration in my Android project:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])   
    compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.0@aar'
    provided 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.+'
}
```

However I can write `compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.0@aar'` line without `@aar`

```
compile 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.0
```

From Appsflyer docs they tell to use `@aar` but since I'm new to gradle, is there any difference with/out `@aar` postfix? Because it looks like works in both cases

Answer (score 1):

Using the `@aar` notation means that you want to download only the aar artifact, and **no dependencies**.
You can check this part of [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html):
Check the `Artifact only notation` section:

> An artifact only notation creates a module dependency which downloads only the artifact file with the specified extension. **Existing module descriptors are ignored**..

Using the `@aar` notation if you want to download the dependencies, you should add `transitive=true`.

Answer (score 0):

AAR is an Android library file

See [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#aar-contents)

The '@aar' indicates that gradle should download an AAR file as opposed to JAR file. In this case my guess would be that the provider of the library forwards requests to the AAR file whether the '@aar' is added or not.